# Generally speaking, when you switch from frying to baking a piece of dough, how should you tweak your recipe?

Tags: baking, dough

Generally speaking, when you switch from frying to baking a piece of dough, how should you tweak your recipe? I used to fry pirozhki (dough with filling, nothing fancy) every five days or so. Now, I can't fry (not with oil, anyway). I tried baking those very same pirozhki under 200°C for 15 minutes and got underwhelming results. They weren't as tender, they were quite thick, not as fluffy. I had made some changes, though. I put a bowl with hot water on the bottom of the oven so that they have a chance to rise before a crust forms (when I fried them, I let them rise for 12 minutes in a warm humid oven before putting them onto a frying pan). What else could I do? Maybe, I should put less fat into my dough? 'cause I baked pizza, it was great, and it contained less fat (just three tablespoons of olive oil per 0.5 kg of flour). The pirozhki dough consists of: 0.5 kg of flour, 280 ml of water, 38 g of butter (don't ask why is not 40 g), two tablespoons of sunflower oil, 15 g of sugar, one teaspoon of salt, yeast. Some folks add egg(s), I don't; some use other kinds of fat (I say it so that I don't appear to claim I cook some "genuine article" pirozhki, maybe they aren't)

Comment: I'm dubious that any general answer could exist, but if you are asking specifically about your pirozhki then there may be some sort of solution. You should consider trying an air fryer if one is available – these work in the same way as a regular oven but the small size enables a more intense heat which might be helpful in this case.

Comment: You should also look for pirozhki recipes designed for the oven (if any exist) as that's probably easier than experimenting with modifying your current recipe.

Comment: I don’t know why you’re avoiding frying, but when I bake empanadas, I brush them with oil so they brown better.  You can also try an egg wash or milk (for the proteins).  I have no idea what needs to be modified in the dough, however

Comment: @dbmag9 no, I don't want to ditch my recipe, it's something I kind of cherish, but I want to adjust it

Comment: @Joe liver problems

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev I can relate to cherishing a recipe, but realistically it will come out so differently baked rather than fried that you will have something different whatever you do. A recipe aimed at baking will just have a better chance at success.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev objectively, adjusting it makes little sense. You won't get the same results as with frying. You can get different results than now, but you will likely invest more work for a result that is worse than a good designed-for-baking recipe. You can continue playing with the recipe for emotional reasons, of course, but then I am a bit of a loss as to how we can be of help, since the process would be basically you making random changes until you hit upon something you like.

Comment: definitely seconding an air fryer. Using a normal oven (with or without fan) you'll struggle to get it behaving anything like frying, and the adjustments to the recipe would likely need to be so drastic as to essentially make it a new recipe anyway. An air fryer will likely be able to better mimic the effects of frying and so require much less adaptation of the recipe (if any)

Comment: @dbmag9 well, that is precisely the question: what IS a recipe aimed at baking? How is it different from a recipe aimed at frying? Technically, you can bake or fry any piece of dough regardless of its composition

Comment: By the way, I don't seek to imitate frying, never said it

Comment: @Tristan what are those drastic changes?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev I don't know enough about pirozhki to really say with much confidence. But in generally baking will take longer to reach the same internal temperature, and the surface won't reach as high a temperature as quickly either meaning you may see different browning/blistering/rising effects. Some of this can be adjusted with changing any leavening or taking other steps to improve browning (I would normally think of an egg-wash, but that probably isn't viable for you, possibly a sprinkle of sugar instead?)